# Swift - How to access cells name

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

```
import UIKit

class TableViewControllerOne: UITableViewController {


  let musicArray = ["Old Town Road", "Starboy"]

  var songName = ""


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return musicArray.count
  }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel!.text = musicArray[indexPath.row]
    //here is the problem
    songName = cell.textLabel!.text!
    return cell
  }

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var vc = segue.destination as! ViewControllerOne
    vc.songFinalName = self.songName
    
  }

}
```

So I am doing music player App, but I don't know how to play current song. I have all songs in a row(identifier is MyCell). When I click on the cell named for example ,,Starboy" it should get that name and pass the data to the other VC and there play it, but always it only plays the latest thing that is in the raw, so for example there are 3 songs: Old Town Road, Starboy, Hello and it can play only the latest so in this example it is Hello. Can someone help me please? Thank you for reading.

Comment: Show your didSelectRow method

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement tableview's delegate method `didSelectRowAt` which will update the `songName` property whenever a user taps on any row of table view

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   songName = musicArray[indexPath.row]
}
```

Moreover, remove `songName = cell.textLabel!.text!` from `cellForRowAt: indexPath` method

Comment: Why not simply set the vc.songFinalName and present the view controller?

Comment: I am thinking for him to make minimal changes to his existing code. I agree best way to trigger the segue should be from the didSelect if you don't have anything big to be taken care of

Comment: So, Thanks fo answering! It kinda works, but it plays the music that I want it to play and then one random music together. I can stop only the ,,random" music. I removed songName = cell.textLabel!.text! from cellForRowAt: indexPath and added override public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        songName = musicArray[indexPath.row]
       // performSegue(withIdentifier: "dataTransport", sender: self)
    } when I add the performSegue... it plays both songs. Without it it play only the random song. Do you know where can be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: It seems something is wrong how you are performing the transition to ViewControllerOne and also how your are assigning the song to songFinalName property of ViewControllerOne. Can you share your performSegue code and also ViewControllerOne code